# SQLAlchemy delete all entries of many to many relationship

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

So I have this program that notes down recipes. a recipe has a number of ingredients and they have a many to many relationship. There is a table of ingredients and they are linked through the recipe_ingredients table to a recipe.

I made the following code to update a recipe (lets say I removed all the ingredients and added a new one), however, instead of clearing the old ingredients, it just appends everything. Am I doing something wrong here?

Update recipe code:

```
@app.route('/recipe', methods=['POST'])
@expects_json(recipeSchema)
def updateRecipe():
    recipeToUpdate = session.query(classes.Recipe).filter(classes.Recipe.id==flask.request.json["id"]).first()
    if recipeToUpdate is not None:
        newRecipe = flask.request.json
        if "name" in newRecipe.keys():
            recipeToUpdate.name = newRecipe["name"]
        if "amountofpeople" in newRecipe.keys():
            recipeToUpdate.amountofpeople = newRecipe["amountofpeople"]
        if "ingredients" in newRecipe.keys():
            newIngredientsArray = []
            for ingredient in newRecipe["ingredients"]:
                if "id" in ingredient.keys():
                    newIngredient = session.query(classes.Ingredient).filter(classes.Ingredient.id==ingredient["id"]).first()
                    newRecipeIngredient = classes.RecipeIngredients(recipe_id=recipeToUpdate.id, ingredient_id=newIngredient.id, ingredient_amount=1)
                    if "ingredient_amount" in ingredient.keys():
                        newRecipeIngredient.ingredient_amount = ingredient["ingredient_amount"]
                    newIngredientsArray.append(newRecipeIngredient)
            recipeToUpdate.ingredients[:] = newIngredientsArray
        session.commit()
        return mapRecipes(recipeToUpdate)
    else:
        return {"id": id, "Error": "Not found"}
```

Recipe:

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipes'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('recipe_id_seq'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    amountofpeople = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    ingredients = relationship("RecipeIngredients", back_populates="recipe")
```

Ingredient:

```
class Ingredient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredients'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    amount = Column(Integer)
    unit = Column(Enum(Units))
    recipe = relationship('RecipeIngredients', back_populates="ingredient")
```

Recipe_ingredients:

```
class RecipeIngredients(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe_ingredients'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
    ingredient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ingredients.id'))
    ingredient_amount = Column(Integer)
    recipe = relationship('Recipe', back_populates="ingredients")
    ingredient = relationship('Ingredient', back_populates="recipe")
```

Comment: Possibly helpful https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#deleting-rows-from-the-many-to-many-table

Comment: Please see [Proxying to Dictionary Based Collections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-to-dictionary-based-collections) which might help you simplify the usage of the n-m relationship.

Comment: As for deletion: deleting all first should solve it, but it might not be most efficient for the database operations and preserving audit/history (in case you need such thing). Hence you might want to split routine into 3 parts: 1. update quantity for existing, 2. remove those not yet found and 3. add new ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, however, I am not sure that it is the right one:

I added: `session.query(classes.RecipeIngredients).filter(classes.RecipeIngredients.recipe_id==recipeToUpdate.id).delete()`
This will first remove all the previous relations before making new ones. but I wonder if there might be a cleaner way by defining a sync in the classes.

```
@app.route('/recipe', methods=['POST'])
@expects_json(recipeSchema)
def updateRecipe():
    recipeToUpdate = session.query(classes.Recipe).filter(classes.Recipe.id==flask.request.json["id"]).first()
    if recipeToUpdate is not None:
        newRecipe = flask.request.json
        if "name" in newRecipe.keys():
            recipeToUpdate.name = newRecipe["name"]
        if "amountofpeople" in newRecipe.keys():
            recipeToUpdate.amountofpeople = newRecipe["amountofpeople"]
        if "ingredients" in newRecipe.keys():
            session.query(classes.RecipeIngredients).filter(classes.RecipeIngredients.recipe_id==recipeToUpdate.id).delete()
            newIngredientsArray = []
            for ingredient in newRecipe["ingredients"]:
                if "id" in ingredient.keys():
                    newIngredient = session.query(classes.Ingredient).filter(classes.Ingredient.id==ingredient["id"]).first()
                    newRecipeIngredient = classes.RecipeIngredients(recipe_id=recipeToUpdate.id, ingredient_id=newIngredient.id, ingredient_amount=1)
                    if "ingredient_amount" in ingredient.keys():
                        newRecipeIngredient.ingredient_amount = ingredient["ingredient_amount"]
                    newIngredientsArray.append(newRecipeIngredient)
            recipeToUpdate.ingredients[:] = newIngredientsArray
        session.commit()
        return mapRecipes(recipeToUpdate)
    else:
        return {"id": id, "Error": "Not found"}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly delete the old ingredients; just replace them [like this](https://pastebin.com/6xQAVRcM).